# Define an easily removable piece of text that synchronises well

Tags: pdftex, environments, pdfsync

I am looking for a command / environment that can easily toggle text, such as

```
  (...)
\def\var{1}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{hello}{  { \if\var1 \BODY \fi  }}
\begin{document}
\begin{hello}
bla bla
    ...
(long removable text)
    ...
\end{hello}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that if I encapsulate a long text in such an environment, and I use alt+click on the pdf in the middle of the text to reach the code (or the opposite), I arrive at  `end{hello}` which is not precise enough.

Does anyone see a way to do that differently to keep the pdfsync capability? I work with texshop on Mac.

Thanks